# My character looks wrong even though everything is ok!

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, eevee-render-engine, error

**While I was examining a model made in blender, I came across the following image:**

[image: wrong model]

**My character's textures are in very good condition. you can see this in eevee mode =**

[image: regular model]

**but the situation worsens when I switch to cycles mode. When I looked at the shaders of this scene, I came across a "group". this =**

[image: light block]

**Even if I put a white "emission" instead of this group, it didn't work.**

[image: shading]

**even in eevee mode, one of the reflecting spheres from the test renders appearing in the lower right is black.**

[image: error]

**I will be glad if you help me. good day!**

Comment: Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date, or in the case of AMD, make sure there are no issues with the current drivers that conflict with blender (It happened once - around Feb this year).

Comment: I am using "Intel driver support assistant" and recently updated my driver. Although my graphics card is very bad, it is also up to date. it also got an update a few days ago. when I opened this file a few months ago there was no problem. I think the problem has a different cause. but thanks for your comment anyway!